# Server error on simple "Delete Sheet / Insert Sheet" script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am receiving a server error on a very simple script, and I'm not sure why. The intent of the script is to check if a sheet already exists. If the sheet does exist, it should be deleted and re-created. If it doesn't exist, it should be created.

The script works fine if the sheet doesn't exist already. If it does exist, the script will delete the sheet and then throw the following error on the line with .insertSheet("Test").

*"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."*

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
function newSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test");
  if(sheet != null){
    spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet); 
  }
  spreadsheet.insertSheet("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, passing in an index...

```
function newSheet() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test");
if (sheet != null) {
    spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
spreadsheet.insertSheet("Test", spreadsheet.getSheets().length);
}
```

and see if that works ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same errors.  It might be a bug.  You'll probably need to use `sheet.clear()`.

Maybe some code like this:

```
function newSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test");
  if(sheet != null){
    sheet.clear();
  } else { 
    spreadsheet.insertSheet("Test");
  }
}
```

Instead of deleting the sheet and creating another sheet of the same name, just clear everything in the current sheet.  I'm not sure what advantage you'd have to deleting the sheet, clearing will hopefully give you the result you want.  If not, I'm curious to know why the sheet needs to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the script is throwing an error if the sheet doesn't exist. You can put it inside a try-catch block.

```
function newSheet() {

  var sheet, spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  try {
    sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test");
    spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
  } catch (e) {};

  spreadsheet.insertSheet("Test");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Amit. The sheet throws the error when it DOES already exist though. Solutions above.